# Know if GCD thread is running

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

In my iOS app I am download a fairly large amount of data in a background thread. What I need to do is somehow check when the user reopens the app if this task is still running or if it has been canceled.

If the user hits the home button for example, and then comes back to the app, the thread will continue which is good. But what if somehow the thread gets torn down by the OS. How can I on app resume know if a thread is running.

Thanks!

Some Code:

```
// Starts a background thread and also allows it to run in the background if the user exits app
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;
    bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [self endBackgroundUpdateTask:bgTask];
    }];

// Code here to run in background

// Tell the main thread its done, and also remove itself from background execution
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"Done with background thread");
    [self endBackgroundUpdateTask:bgTask];
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off any thread, foreground or background will be suspended when your App goes into the background. There are some things you can do to get a small amount of time as you transition into the background to finish up and cleanup.... but your definitely getting shut down,  "background" thread or not, when your app leaves the screen.

That means your download will have been suspended and you will have to gracefully recover and resume where you left off. For that you should investigate the techniques iOS offers for being notified your going into the background and being allowed some extra time to clean up and save some state that can be used to resume.

Investigate this:

```
   beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler
```

Then use backgroundTimeRemaining to check how much time is left as you try to finish up in the extra time granted. When it's clear you can't finish in the allotted time save state and set a flag that indicates you need to continue or start over when the you re-launch. There is really no other way as iOS doesn't have any way of knowing if you finished what you were trying to do and it is up to you to

Comment: Yes that would be true but look at the code I posted. I am already using beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler and that works fine. But say the task takes longer than the system gives it. So then it will gracefully shut down the thread. When the user opens the app again, I want to check that it got shot down so I can start the download again.

Comment: Ok, then.. it's fairly simply use: backgroundTimeRemaining to check how much time is left as you try to finish up. When it winds down and it's clear your not going to make it. Save state, set a flag that you need to continue with the download at next launch and call endBackgroundUpdateTask. There is really no other way.